# How to find the missing value using knn in R

Tags: r, dataset, knn

Here is the dataset I created:

```
ID <- c('X',1,2,3)
Age <- c(30,25,33,35)
Asset_Size <- c(60,50,60,80)
Income <- c(NA,100000,90000,150000)
chart1 <- data.frame(ID,Age,Asset_Size,Income)
```

I'm trying to find the missing value of income for customer X if K = 3 and method = “distance weighted vote". So far I've done it with an "unweighted vote" method and this is what it looks like.

```
train <- chart1[2:4, 2:3]
test <- chart1[1, 2:3]
cl <- chart1[2:4, 1]
knn(train, test, cl, k = 3, prob = T)
```

How would I go about finding the missing value using a K = 3 and a “distance weighted vote" method? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require(VIM)
require(laeken)
kNN(chart1, k = 3, numFun = weightedMean, weightDist=TRUE)

Time difference of 0.008000851 secs
  ID Age Asset_Size   Income ID_imp Age_imp Asset_Size_imp Income_imp
1  X  30         60 106666.7  FALSE   FALSE          FALSE       TRUE
2  1  25         50 100000.0  FALSE   FALSE          FALSE      FALSE
3  2  33         60  90000.0  FALSE   FALSE          FALSE      FALSE
4  3  35         80 150000.0  FALSE   FALSE          FALSE      FALSE
```

Comment: It's saying Error in knn(chart1, k = 3, numFun = weightedMean, weightDist = TRUE) : 
  unused arguments (numFun = weightedMean, weightDist = TRUE)

Comment: @Tomas That's because you changed `kNN` to `knn`. They are different KNN functions. This one is from the `VIM` package. Make sure you copy and paste the code from my answer. Install the packages if you don't have them.

Comment: It told me that it could not find function "kNN" so I switched it to the regular knn function. I think I'm missing something here. I did just install VIM and laeken

Comment: Ok there was an error in installing Vim. I'll see what it is. Thanks

Comment: @Tomas OK cool. Make sure you type it as `VIM` not `Vim` and load the library after you install it.

Comment: This is what it said Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘pbkrtest’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘VIM’ was built under R version 3.2.5

Comment: I'm guessing my R version is not up to date?

Comment: @Tomas Correct. It will most likely work anyway, but that is why you get that warning, yes. Regarding the error before the warning, I'm not sure if that's referring to a dependency or something else you're trying to install. If it's a dependency then the 2 things you can do are 1. Upgrade R and optionally 2. Use a package manager such as `pacman` to do the installation for you. `if(!require(pacman)) install.packages("pacman"); pacman::p_load(VIM, laeken)`